# Can't remove %s from display

Tags: java, android, xml

[image: Why is %s getting printed?]

I want to remove the %s from being shown on the screen, but don't know what i'm doing wrong. Any help?

Strings.xml file -

```
<!-- Name of the customer [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="user_name">
        Name: <xliff:g id="name" example="Amy">%s</xliff:g>
    </string>
```

Main XML file -

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint = "@string/user_name"
        android:id = "@+id/name_input"/>
```

Java file -

```
String priceMessage = getString(R.string.user_name, customer);
```

Comment: Do you need to remove it from placeholder? When you just need to change android:hint property to a string that doesn't contain %s

Comment: I want to keep the hint as a referenced string so it changes itself with the language.

Comment: Why not make another string resource for that? Like `<string name="user_name">Your name</string>`

Comment: What is this `xliff:g`?

Comment: You didn't provide coding to resource tag such as : `<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
  <!-- Name of the customer [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
<string name="user_name">
    Name: <xliff:g id="name" example="Amy">%s</xliff:g>
</string>
```

To:

```
 <!-- Name of the customer [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
<string name="user_name">Name:</string>
```

Then, when you reference this string in Java, the value will change to the specific language of your choice as long as you have added specific `strings.xml` files for that particular language.

Comment: But then the hint wouldn't change itself with different languages would it? I want to have that flexibility.